# Unable to see see Layout for DocuSign to add to Salesforce instance

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi, docusignconnect

Trying to Setup DocuSign in Salesforce.

In the DocuSign Admin Tab have an to add the Layout to which I want the DocuSign to show up. But Under 'Layouts', I do not see any thing. Also check for remote settings and looks correct.

Anyone with same issue?

Thanks

Comment: me too is no answer

Comment: What are you trying to add in the layout? are you talking about the "Send with DocuSign Button"?

Answer (score 0):

try:
In Salesforce | Setup | Security | Remote Sites - add a new Remote Site: https://{custom domain} and layouts will be displayed in the DocuSign eSignature for Salesforce Admin tab.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have already tried that. but it is still not working